# Datatables with ajax response (Use of undefined constant)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, datatables, laravel-blade

How to use a JavaScript variable inside Blade syntax? I'm getting an error:

> Use of undefined constant buttonID

#### inded.blade.php

```
var t = $("#datatable").DataTable({
    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
    "ajax": "questions1/get-data",
    "deferRender": true,
    "processing": true,
    sAjaxDataProp: "",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "description" },
        { "data": "answers.[, ].name" },
        { "data": "campaigns.[, ].name" },
        { "data": "label" },
        {
            sortable: false,
            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                var buttonID = full.id;
                return '@can('delete', $question){!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE','url' => ['/admin/survey-details/questions', buttonID ],'style' => 'display:inline']) !!}{!! Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete Question" />', array('type' => 'submit','class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs','title' => 'Delete Question','onclick'=>'return confirm("Confirm delete?")')) !!}{!! Form::close() !!}@endcan';
            }
        }

    ],

});
```

Comment: You can't execute php from the client side

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute php from the client side, you can use concatenation to append the id a the end of the url using js

```
  var t = $("#datatable").DataTable({
            "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
            "ajax": "questions1/get-data",
            "deferRender": true,
            "processing": true,
            sAjaxDataProp: "",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "description" },
                { "data": "answers.[, ].name" },
                { "data": "campaigns.[, ].name" },
                { "data": "label" },
                {
                    sortable: false,
                    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                        var buttonID = full.id;
                        return '@can('delete', $question){
                           <form action="{{url("/admin/survey-details/questions")/'+buttonID+'"style="display:inline">
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Delete Question" onclick=>"return confirm('Confirm delete?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete Question" /></button>
     </form>

                         }@endcan';
                    }
                }

            ],



 });
```

Comment: don't forget to push the green check :)